# Finding the strongest normal form and if it isn't in BCNF decompose it?

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, decomposition, bcnf

I know how to do these problems easily when the input is basic. I know the rules for the 1st,2nd,and 3rd normal forms as well as BCNF. HOWEVER I was looking through some practice exercises and I saw some unusual input:

> Consider the following collection of relations and dependencies.
> Assume that each relation is obtained through decomposition from a
> relation with attributes ABCDEFGHI and that all the known
> dependencies over relation ABCDEFGHI are listed for each question.
> (The questions are independent of each other, obviously, since the given dependencies over ABCDEFGHI are different.)
>
> 1. R2(A,B,F) AC → E, B → F
> 2. R1(A,C,B,D,E) A → B, C → D

I can solve 2:

```
A+=AB
C+=CD
AC+=ABCD
ACE=ABCDE
```

So ACE is the candidate key, and none of A, C and E are superkeys. It isn't bcnf for sure. Decompose it and obtain (ACE)(AB)(CD) etc etc.

BUT Number 1 is confusing me! Why is there AC → E when neither C nor E is in R2? How could this be solved? It can't be an error because many other exercises are like this :/

Another question, what happens when one functional dependency is in BCNF and others are not? Do we just ignore this functional dependency while decomposing the others into BCNF?

Comment: A FD cannot be "in" a NF. A relation is in or not in a given NF, and is in a highest NF from some understood set of NFs, depending on the FDs that hold in it. A design or set of relations is in or not in a NF when all of its relations are. What are you trying to say? Maybe something about, given some FDs that hold & a defintion of a NF, the FD might or might not "violate" that NF per the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the text of the exercise, the dependencies are those holding on the original relation (ABCDEFGHI): “all the known dependencies over relation ABCDEFGHI are listed for each question”.

So, assuming that in the original relation the only specified dependencies are `AC → E` and `B → F`, this means that the dependency `AC → E` is lost in the decomposed relation `R2(A,B,F)`, that the (only) candidate key of the relation is `AB`, the schema is not in 2NF (since `F` depends on a part of a key), and that to decompose that schema in BCNF you must decompose it in `(AB)` and `(BF)`.